# better understanding of onTouchListener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I've came across something strange, I want to listen for clicks and when it happens I want to get it's directions, but the click seems to happen three times, what is the cause of it?

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                int x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                int y = (int) motionEvent.getY();
                Log.i(LOGGING_CONST, "click performed x: " + x + " y: " + y);
            }
        }
    });

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    return super.performClick();
}
```

Logcat after one click:

```
I/GAME_VIEW_CLASS:: click performed x: 481 y: 804
I/GAME_VIEW_CLASS:: click performed x: 481 y: 804
I/GAME_VIEW_CLASS:: click performed x: 481 y: 804
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are listening touch events and touch events triggers on every finger movements. Try to listen onDown event. As an example;

```
        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    int x = (int) event.getX();
                    int y = (int) event.getY();
                    Log.i(LOGGING_CONST, "click performed x: " + x + " y: " + y);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you are listening all kind of touch events as ACTION_DOWN,ACTION_MOVE,ACTION_CANCEL

if you want single tap click then listen ACTION_DOWN alone,

switch(event.ACTION_DOWN):

{

do your code here for single click

}

refer below link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent